# HTTP load failed (error code: -1005) iOS

Tags: ios, http, server, httprequest, alamofire

In my app, I use Alamofire to fetch data from my server. For each time I fetch, 10 results will be sent from my server to my app. If I only post 3 requests or less at the same time, no any issue. If I post 5 or more requests at the same time, I received below error (1). After about 60s, I received below error (2). I am wondering this is my server issue or ?? Any suggestions? Thanks.

error(1) - 1005

```
2017-11-25 17:12:31.645624+0800 LeanCloudStarter[2044:84112] Task <520034AA-B195-4354-ADB6-3544C5907E22>.<69> HTTP load failed (error code: -1005 [4:-4])
2017-11-25 17:12:31.646056+0800 LeanCloudStarter[2044:83813] Task <520034AA-B195-4354-ADB6-3544C5907E22>.<69> finished with error - code: -1005
```

error(2) - 1001

```
2017-11-25 20:59:42.370155+0800 LeanCloudStarter[4098:180387] TIC TCP Conn Failed [110:0x600000172fc0]: 1:60 Err(60)
2017-11-25 20:59:42.370640+0800 LeanCloudStarter[4098:180387] Task <A951A3F1-B8B3-415B-9BBA-AFDF039A57C3>.<125> HTTP load failed (error code: -1001 [1:60])
2017-11-25 20:59:42.371383+0800 LeanCloudStarter[4098:180306] Task <A951A3F1-B8B3-415B-9BBA-AFDF039A57C3>.<125> finished with error - code: -1001
```

Comment: I think this is because of your API timeout ... your server can't respond more than 5 requests at the same time ... check your server logs

Comment: Exactly, you are right.